# jQuery Datatable cache problems with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, datatable

I'm using the jQuery Datatables for showing a list of logged in people. It contains for each person a cell with the picture, login date/time, name, information.
A user can update his profile picture which is shown in one of the cells. The Datatable refreshes every two seconds using the this:

```
    ajax: 'scripts/loggedinlist.php',

setInterval(function(){
   mytable.fnReloadAjax('scripts/loggedinlist.php');
 }, 2000);
```

When the user updates his picture, it keeps showing up the old one. I have to clear the browser cache to see the new one.

I tried adding the

```
cache: false
```

option and i disabled the google chromes browser caching - still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make url with datetime `img.png?+new Date().getTime()` this will give every time new image without cache.

Comment: Hi, this is working very well! But it causes the Datatable to flicker somehow. Looks like i should try to store the last updated time() in the database and add it as the parameter, so it only changes if a change was made, right?

Comment: Use it only at show item.

Comment: that's what i did. now since i am storing a time() for a field like "lastupdated" it works very nice without flickering. Thanks!

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `URL` with `img.png?+new Date().getTime()` or as you have `lastupdated` field `img.png?+lastupdated`

that will get solve your problem with `image` `cache`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
 setInterval(function(){
   $("#Your_Table_Id").dataTable().fnDraw();
 }, 2000);
```

Comment: try to get your image from your query and as you are using datatables then obviously you can edit the column, andset your image path .

let me know if you dont understand anywhere.